# A Cohen-Macaulay localisation

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

> Let $R=\mathbb C[X,Y]/(Y^3-X^3)$, let $x,y$ be the images of $X,Y$ in $R$, and let $R_1$ be the localization of $R$ at the maximal ideal $(x,y)$. I want to prove that $R_1$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring.

If we could see that $R_1$ is of Krull dimension $1$ then we are done since any domain of K-dim $1$ is Cohen-Macaulay.  I think that $R_1=\mathbb C[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(x_0,y_0)$, where $x_0,y_0$ are the images of $X,Y$ in $\mathbb C[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}$. Is this latter true? Thanks for any cooperation!

Comment: First, $R_1$ is not a domain (I am assuming that you meant $Y^3-X^3$), so you can not argue the way you suggest. I suggest you look these up in a book dealing with Cohen-Macaulay rings and modules. One of the basic facts they will all prove is that if $S$ is a Cohen-Macaulay local ring and $a\in S$ is a non-unit, non-zero divisor, then $S/aS$ is Cohen-Macaulay too. You can use this with $S$ the localization of the polynomial ring and $a=X^3-Y^3$.

Comment: Actually $R_1=\mathbb C[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(Y^3-X^3)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, $R$ is a one dimensional *reduced* (why?) ring, and such rings are Cohen-Macaulay. Therefore all its localizations are Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: Thanks for the leading comment and answer. If the quotient is by $Y^2-X^3$, is my suggestion true? And how $R_1$ is C-M? Thanks again.

Comment: @karparvar Yes, then you argument is correct. The polynomial $Y^2-X^3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb C[X,Y]$, so $R$ (and therefore all its localizations) is an integral domain.

Comment: To see (traditionally at least) that $R_1$ is of K-dim $1$ we can check the height of the maximal ideal $(x,y)$ to be $1$. In fact, this ideal must not contain any nonzero prime ideal, why?

Comment: @karparvar The height of the maximal ideal $(X,Y)$ equals two, and the height of the quotient $(X,Y)/(Y^2-X^3)$ drops by one.